# how to return results to postman using nodejs.i couldn't send result

Tags: node.js

```
App.js
app.get('/getCus', function (req, res) {
  var id= req.query;
  cus_controller.getCus(id,function(response) {
    res.json(response);
  });
});

cus_controller.js:
module.exports ={
 getCus: function (id, callback) {
        getCus = function () {
            getOneCus(id).then(result => {
                callback(result);
            }).catch(err => {
                callback(err)
            })
        }
        process.nextTick(getCus);
    },
}
async function getOneCus(id) {
    auth.authClient(function (err, client) {
    if (client) {
        function callback(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
               console.log(body);
            }
        }
    getCus(id,client, callback);
    }
    else {
        console.error(err);
    }
    })
}
var getCus = (id, client, callback) => {
    
    client
        .invokeApi(null, `/cus/${id}`, 'GET')
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result.data);
            return result.data
        })
        .catch(function (result) {
            if (result.response) {
                console.dir({
                    status: result.response.status,
                    statusText: result.response.statusText,
                    data: result.response.data
                });
            } else {
                console.log(result.message);
            }
        });
}
```

in getCus method getting a response in the console. however, couldn't get a response in postman.it shows 200 status code but didn't get a response. Someone help me, please. I could not find any solution for this.i tried many methods like return data and res.send(data).[image]

Comment: in returns empty.in return result.data is not coming

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a callback function to `getCus`, but you never use it.  It looks like you meant call it instead of return the result:

```
client
    .invokeApi(null, `/cus/${id}`, 'GET')
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result.data);
        callback(result.data); // <-- here
    })
```

Alternatively, if you `return` the result as you currently do, then you wouldn't pass a callback to `getCus` but would instead use a `.then()` structure:

```
cus_controller.getCus(id).then(function(response) {
    res.json(response);
});
```

But be sure to also return the top-level Promise by returning the call to `client.invokeApi`:

```
return client // <-- here
    .invokeApi(null, `/cus/${id}`, 'GET')
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log(result.data);
        return result.data
    })
```

Comment: @umaraja: Looking over the code some more... You have *two* things named `getCus`.  Which one are you actually calling?  Giving multiple things the same name is a recipe for confusion here.  You're also re-assigning one of the two `getCus` functions to another function inside of the other `getCus` function, before calling `getCus` in the other function that the other `getCus` calls.  This is probably a good time to refactor your code a bit to be more clear.  But ultimately, whatever path your code is taking, you either need to return the relevant `Promise` or invoke the relevant callback.